# No AJAX refresh after button click? ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile, button

I'm creating a page using jQuery Mobile. Basically what I want, is a button click (from C# Behind) to run a PHP script, but not refresh the page. I realize that an AJAX refresh is kinda different, but I would love to just click the button, run the script (all on the server behind) and keep the page looking the same without the fancy spinning wheel.

Is this possible? Also, if more info is needed, I'm happy to provide.

Thanks in advance!

(Also, the button affects nothing on the actual page, that's why the refresh is slightly annoying)

Comment: Have you tried adding `data-ajax=false` to the button?

Comment: Can you post the code and how you refresh the page?